# Different representation of UUID in Java Hibernate and SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am trying to map a `UUID` column in POJO to SQL Server table column using Hibernate.

The annotations are applied as follows:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "Id", columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier") 
public UUID getId(){ ... }
```

However, it seems that there is some endianness problem between the Java Hibernate mapping and SQL server.

For example, in my Java app, I have ids represented as:

```
4375CF8E-DEF5-43F6-92F3-074D34A4CE35
ADE3DAF8-A62B-4CE2-9D8C-B4E4A54E3DA1
```

whereas in SQL Server, these are represented as:

```
8ECF7543-F5DE-F643-92F3-074D34A4CE35
F8DAE3AD-2BA6-E24C-9D8C-B4E4A54E3DA1
```

Is there any way to have same representation at both sides?

Please note that `uniqueidentifier` is used only to have a `uniqueidentifier` typed id in SQL server instead of type `binary`; the same problem exists when `uniqueidentifier` is removed from annotation (the problem can be observed by converting `binary` is to `uniqueidentifier`).

Comment: is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745512/how-to-read-a-net-guid-into-a-java-uuid

Comment: is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22402929/uuid-madness-with-mssql

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48918942/2102158

Comment: How to convert from one pf above format to another using sql script?

Answer (score 42):

You need to specify the `@Type(type = "uuid-char")` in addition to `@Column(name="...", columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier")`, see also [Problems mapping UUID in JPA/hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346898/problems-mapping-uuid-in-jpa-hibernate) .

Alternatively you can use a `String` field for the id in Java and still keep `uniqueidentifier` in SQL Server.

Comment: Originally I thought this wasn't correct, but have confirmed it works, if you use   
        @Column(columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier")
 @Type(type = "uuid-char")

It ensures that the column type is created as "uniqueidentifier", but when reading/writing to the DB the UUID order is as expected (I.e. when you view the field in SSMS, it looks the same as when you use .toString() on the UUID).

Comment: This no longer works since Hibernate 6

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft databases use GUIDs. It is Microsoft's implementation of the UUID standard.

This being said, you should use the guid generator.

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "guid", parameters = {})
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

> `guid` uses a database-generated GUID string on MS SQL Server and
>   MySQL.

Also, have you set SQLServer2012Dialect? This also might solve some future issues.

Comment: I tried the solution but it didn't work, My database has One GUID but when I fetch the data from the table, it generates different UUID.
Any sort of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

With SQL Server you should use **guid** strategy for your generator:

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "my-uid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "my-uid", strategy = "guid")
@Id
private UUID uuid;
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html

Java is using UUID generator in version 4 how can you see here:

4375CF8E-DEF5-**4**3F6-92F3-074D34A4CE35

ADE3DAF8-A62B-**4**CE2-9D8C-B4E4A54E3DA1