# issues with UUID in java and uniqueidentifier in sql server

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, uuid

I have an entity (Car) which is mapped to a table in DB (car).
The id of the POJO Car is of UUID and column type of car table is of `uniqueidentifier`.

The id field looks like this:

```
  @Id
  @Type(type = "uuid-char")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
  @Column(columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier", name = "id")
  private UUID id;


  @NotNull
  @Type(type = "uuid-char")
  @ApiModelProperty(required = true, example = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
  @Column(columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier", name = "make_id")
  private UUID makeId;
```

The id should be generated and save to DB. But the id was saved wrong.
Same problem here. [Different representation of UUID in Java Hibernate and SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41651681/different-representation-of-uuid-in-java-hibernate-and-sql-server)

I took the `@Type(type = "uuid-char")` solution and it solved the problem indeed. The id was saved to the db correctly.

But when doing a `getById`. It seems like hibernate can't find the record by `id`.

I am using spring boot repository.  Using native query cannot find by `id`.

```
 @Query(value = QUERY_JOIN + " WHERE lv.car_makeId = ?1 ", nativeQuery = true)
  public List<Car> getCar(UUID makeId);
```

However, the following is fine:

```
public List<Car> findByMakeId(UUID makeId);
```

I am sure the native query is fine. Maybe hibernate is doing some converting/formatting to the UUID?

like: `@Type(type = "uuid-char")` tells hibernate. "don't do anything with the id. just store it as it is'. But when doing a get using the correct id. It's not able to find it even it's right there in the DB. So, I am guessing that before it uses the id to do a lookup. it's still doing something with it (converting/ formatting) so that it's wrong again. so that it can't find anything
any ideas what am I doing wrong in here?