# UUID's storing in a different way in sql server

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, uuid

I am storing UUIDs as a primary key.

```
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID_GENERATOR")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID_GENERATOR", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "store_id")
    private UUID storeId;
```

The problem with this  is in sql_server the UUIDs are storing a different order compared to what I got from the JSON output.

**JSON output**

```
 "storeId": "3854fe95-e6b6-4319-9d9a-bfe67c9a07d6",
```

**Database**

```
storeID: "95FE5438-B6E6-1943-9D9A-BFE67C9A07D6"
```

The initial 8-4-4 digits are storing in a different order whereas last 4-12 digits are same. What is the reason for this issue and how to solve this?

Comment: JSON output *from where*? How did you derive the JSON output, how did you store the data in SQL Server, and how are you retrieving the data from SQL Server?

Comment: Maybe the column is set to auto gen the uid.

Comment: @AaronBertrand  from the endpoint that I used to post the data to the db.

Comment: @JacobH I didn't get it

Comment: That's not very specific. I don't know what your endpoint is and I don't even know which of my questions you're answering there. Best of luck. /shrug

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different representation of UUID in Java Hibernate and SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41651681/different-representation-of-uuid-in-java-hibernate-and-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

The difference is endianness; Microsoft likes to store the first half as little endian, which is a bit odd because they always store the second half as big endian. Everyone else stores the entire thing as big endian, which makes things much simpler and more portable.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using Hibernate then this code should work:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
@Column(columnDefinition="uniqueidentifier")
protected UUID id;
```